# slide form up when keyboard appears

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

hello i am using a form  for data entry ,
some of the textfields are in the bottom of form.
when i click on text fields for writing, keyboard appears and hides the fields behing it. if i make textfield first responder it hides keyboard but by doing this i am unable to do this.
i want to know how it is possible that when keyboard appears, whole form should move up in the way that my last field is appearing on the op of key board
thanks in advance

Comment: See also: [Making the view slide up to make room for the keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892205/making-the-view-slide-up-to-make-room-for-the-keyboard).

Answer (score 6):

Add all of your view in a scroll view and set delegate of scroll view and textfield then use these delegate and method -

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

   [self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:textField];     
    return YES;

}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    if ([textField isEqual:txtField1])
    {
        [txtField2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if ([textField isEqual:txtField2])
    {
        [txtField3 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else 
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];       
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
    }

    return YES;

}

- (void)scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:(UIView *)theView {  
    CGFloat viewCenterY = theView.center.y;  
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];  

    CGFloat availableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - 200;            // Remove area covered by keyboard  

    CGFloat y = viewCenterY - availableHeight / 2.0;  
    if (y < 0) {  
        y = 0;  
    }  
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:YES];  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several strategies you can use to do this -- most of them involve wrapping your view in a UIScrollView and scrolling to the appropriate control as it gets focus. You can find Apple's documentation on how to do this here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html