# how to slide screen in iphone app to look the data which we are entering in textfield

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making the view slide up to make room for the keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892205/making-the-view-slide-up-to-make-room-for-the-keyboard)
>   [Xcode/iOS5: Move UIView up, when keyboard appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952762/xcode-ios5-move-uiview-up-when-keyboard-appears)

As we normally enter data in textfield keyboard appears and it hides the data what we are entering in fields so is there any way that screen should slide up so that we can see data which is entered in the fiedl.

Comment: Possibly Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952762/xcode-ios5-move-uiview-up-when-keyboard-appears , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893122/slide-form-up-when-keyboard-appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code.......

```
 -(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
 {
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // if you want to slide up the view

CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
if (movedUp)
{
    rect.origin.y -= moveKeyboard;
}
else
{
    rect.origin.y += moveKeyboard;
}
self.view.frame = rect;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

  -(void)keyboardWillShow
 {
// Animate the current view out of the way
if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
{
    [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
}
else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
{
    [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
}
 }


 -(void)keyboardWillHide
 {
if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
{
    [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
}
else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
{
    [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
}
}


 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
// register for keyboard notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
 }
 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
// unregister for keyboard notifications while not visible.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
 }
```

Edit: moveKeyboard is float. Set its value according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

There are notifications ([`UIKeyboard[Will|Did][Show|Hide]Notification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW16)) that tell you the keyboard is about to appear or disappear, and you can use those to trigger the code that moves your views. There are different ways to move the views -- you can move them yourself, adjusting their positions as you like; you can put them all inside a single view so that you only have to move the container; or you can embed them in a scroll view and simply adjust the content offset for the scroll view.

See Apple's document [Managing the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), and in particular the section called [Moving Content That is Located Under the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7). There's sample code there, too, and it works quite well.