# Scroll on textField when begin Editing and keyboard appear

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield

I've a viewController composed by an UIImageView that fills the whole view and two textField located at the center of the view. All this is located inside a ScrollView.
I use Storyboard and I disabled the autolayout.
When I click on a textField, and thus opens the keyboard, I'd like that the scroll is displaced directly on textField. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Consider that your TextField outlet is named `txtField` then implement [UITextField Delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) using

```
txtField.delegate = self;
```

Considering that your ScrollView outlet is named `scrollView`. Implement the Textfield Delegate method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(textField.frame));
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textField.frame animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Do let me know if you need more help.

Comment: It don't work.I followed everything you told me. Remember that I don't use the autolayout.

Comment: @Pinturikkio: Do you have a scrollView? Also does your textfield hide behind your keyboard? Also is your textfield inside your scrollview?

Comment: @Pinturikkio: Also with my updated answer above check what is the frame logged in console? When you click in the textfield?

Comment: I've a scrollView yes! My textField is inside my scrollView. The output in the console: {{41, 325}, {240, 30}}

Comment: @Pinturikkio Ok make sure that even with your keyboard open (visible on screen) there is some part of scrollView which is visible. You can check this by setting some color to your scrollview background. If that is the case then my code should work for you as then when you click in textField the scrollView should scroll to make textField frame visible.

Comment: Here the code of my viewDidLoad:
UIColor *viewColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:197/255.0 green:199/255.0 blue:200/255.0 alpha:1];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:viewColor];
    _scroll.delegate = self;
    _scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
    _scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 800);
    _txtMail.delegate = self;
    _txtPassword.delegate = self;

Comment: In storyboard I've a viewController. 
The hierarchical structure is as follows:
-View
---ScrollView
-------- ImageView - myImage.png //image that fills the entire screen
-------- Button - Login
-------- Text Field - mail
-------- Text Field - password

Comment: @Pinturikkio Can you please tell me whether scrollview is visible when keyboard is visible?

Comment: Yes i can use, if I pull up and down, the view makes scrolling. But I want that when you open the keyboard, the scrollView go directly where there is the textField

Comment: so what? How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this successfully:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Answer (score 0):

Add your controller as an observer of the keyboard notifications. When you receive the notification, resize the scroll view frame and / or set the content offset (depending on the exact effect you want and content size you have).

Answer (score 0):

Here are several options that I've used before:

- Apple's Doco. See the section titled [Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW3)
- Cocoa With Love article, [Sliding UITextFields around to avoid the keyboard](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html)
- If you have several text fields or other form elements in your view, you could alternatively use something like [EZForm](https://github.com/chrismiles/EZForm). It does automatic repositioning of views to keep input fields visible, and also handles input validation and other useful form-related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the text field coordinate system into Scroll view coordinate system. Use the below code

```
-(void)rearrangeView{
    // previous

    if (txtActiveField == txtUsername) {
        CGPoint pt;
        CGRect rc = [txtUsername bounds];
        rc = [txtUsername convertRect:rc toView:scrollViewLogin];
        pt = rc.origin;
        pt.x = 0;
        pt.y -= 40;
        [scrollViewLogin setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];
    }
    else if (txtActiveField == txtPassword) {
        // [self.txtEmail becomeFirstResponder];
        CGPoint pt;
        CGRect rc = [txtPassword bounds];
        rc = [txtPassword convertRect:rc toView:scrollViewLogin];
        pt = rc.origin;
        pt.x = 0;
        pt.y -= 40;
        [scrollViewLogin setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];
    }
}

#pragma mark- UITextField Delegate
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    txtActiveField = textField;
    //txtActiveField.placeholder = @"";
    [self rearrangeView];

    return YES;
}
```

Here txtActiveField is instance variable of type UItextField